# How to select .not(this) inside a particular element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, this

I have created a function that fades in some descriptive information when an `li` element is clicked. The function fades the new information within the list.  The line that is not working is `$(".hover").not(".hover", this).fadeOut(200).removeClass("not-me");` and understand that it is down to `.not(".hover", this)`.

I have tried `.not(this)` but this is not working correctly. Presumably because the `this` part of it is still selected from the `li` element, originally from the click function `$("ul li").click(function() {`.

Is there a way to use `.not(".hover", this)` successfully?

**jQuery:**

```
$("ul li").click(function() {

  // Remove other divs with element currently shown
  $(".hover").not(".hover", this).fadeOut(200).removeClass("not-me");

  // Stop chosen element from fading out
  $(".hover", this).addClass("not-me").fadeIn(200);

});
```

**HTML:**

```
<li>
  <div class="hover">
     <h3>Header</h3>
     <p>Shot but breif description, cut me off if you need to.</p>
   </div>
   <img src="/images/1.jpg" alt="" />
</li>
<li>
  <div class="hover">
     <h3>Header</h3>
     <p>Shot but breif description, cut me off if you need to.</p>
   </div>
   <img src="/images/2.jpg" alt="" />
</li>
<li>
  <div class="hover">
     <h3>Header</h3>
     <p>Shot but breif description, cut me off if you need to.</p>
   </div>
   <img src="/images/3.jpg" alt="" />
</li>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for this:

```
$("li").not(this).find(".hover");
```

which will give you all `.hover` elements, excluding children of `this`.

---

You should probably cache that `$('li')` object...

Comment: Unfortunately, I have tried `$(".hover").not(this)` and it does not work. The reason for this is because `this` is selecting the `li` (which comes from `$("ul li").click(function() {`).

Comment: @Titanium Do note that your `'li'` selector is not anchored to anything, so if you have another `<ul>` on the page somewhere, it might get affected too.

Comment: In my actual code it is anchored to a unique element but for the purposes of this example, I removed it. But thanks for the concern!

Answer (score 1):

`.not` only takes one argument.  Also, it's impossible for anything to satisfy `$(".hover").not(".hover")`.  Just use `$(".hover").not(this)`

http://api.jquery.com/not/

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty straightforward when you use `.siblings()`. It's also anchored in the sense that it doesn't take `<li>` outside of the current `<ul>` into consideration.

Having said that, your initial selector of `$('ul li')`, unless intended, may not be appropriate if you later add more lists to the page.

```
$("ul li").click(function() {

  // Remove other divs with element currently shown
  $(this)
      .siblings() // get sibling li's
          .find('.hover') // and fadeout their inner .hover divs
              .fadeOut(200)
              .removeClass("not-me")
              .end()
          .end()
      .find('.hover')
          .fadeIn(200)
          .addClass("not-me")
});
```

Comment: You are quite right, I tested it with the typo and it did not work but the code above works perfectly as well.  In this case, I will use Joseph's answer to save a couple of bytes but it is a good example of the `sibilings()` selector.

Comment: I've just noticed your function takes care of both the fading in and out!

Comment: Haha, that's a good thing! Just adding up the characters to see what would be more efficient (but I suppose that requires how the selectors link to jQuery). But then we're getting into minute numbers which is just ridiculous. Both great answers that work very well!